# Error: Purchase failed with code: 8(null) React-native In-app purchase

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to consume the purchase, but getting this error. Here is my code below.

```
RNIap.getPurchaseHistory()
      .then(productsHistory => {
        RNIap.consumePurchase(productsHistory[0].purchaseToken)
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.code);
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err); 
  }
```

Comment: I have also same Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked!!!

```
    RNIap.getAvailablePurchases()
      .then(availablePurchases=> {
        RNIap.consumePurchase(availablePurchases[0].purchaseToken)
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.code);
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err); 
  }
```

Never mind!

Comment: I got It. This is really helpful for me.